# AutoMapper setting destination object to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have been following this article: https://medium.com/ps-its-huuti/how-to-get-started-with-automapper-and-asp-net-core-2-ecac60ef523f

But when I get to the actual mapping part my destination is null.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddScoped<ICreditCardApplicationRepository,
                           EntityFrameworkCreditCardApplicationRepository>();

        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

CreditCardApplicationProfile

```
public class CreditCardApplicationProfile : Profile
{
    public CreditCardApplicationProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<NewCreditCardApplicationDetails, CreditCardApplication>();
    }   
}
```

Full ApplyController.cs, but I am interested in the HttpPost Index method.

```
public class ApplyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICreditCardApplicationRepository _applicationRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;


    public ApplyController(
        ICreditCardApplicationRepository applicationRepository,
        IMapper mapper
    )
    {
        _applicationRepository = applicationRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(NewCreditCardApplicationDetails applicationDetails)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(applicationDetails);
        }

        CreditCardApplication cca = _mapper.Map<CreditCardApplication>(applicationDetails);

        await _applicationRepository.AddAsync(cca);

        return View("ApplicationComplete", cca);
    }

    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I intially only had the line
    CreditCardApplication cca = _mapper.Map(applicationDetails);

but the comiler complained :

```
The type arguments for method 'IMapper.Map<TDestination>(object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

This led to me trying to specify the type and at this point, it now returns null. Can anyone tell me what I doing wrong, please?

Adding class definitions below:

```
public class CreditCardApplication
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public decimal GrossAnnualIncome { get; set; }
    public string FrequentFlyerNumber { get; set; }
}



public class NewCreditCardApplicationDetails
{
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a first name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a last name")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Age (in years)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide an age in years")]
    [Range(18,int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You must be at least 18 years old")]
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Gross Income")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your gross income")]        
    public decimal? GrossAnnualIncome { get; set; }
    public string FrequentFlyerNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the whole object null, or just certain property(ies)?

Comment: thanks for coming back - it's the whole object. i also tried being type explicit with both source and destination but same result of a null assignment : CreditCardApplication cca = _mapper.Map<NewCreditCardApplicationDetails, CreditCardApplication>(applicationDetails);

Comment: You definitely need to specify the destination type in the type param. The only time you can use `Map` without specifying a type is when you're mapping onto an existing instance e.g `_mapper.Map(source, destination)`, because it can infer both types. You do not ever need to pass both types as type params because it can always infer at least the source type.

Comment: That said, the only way it would make sense for the entire destination object to be null is if the entire source object was also null. Are you sure it has a value?

Comment: yes - it definitely has a value. i can see the NewCreditCardApplicationDetails object coming into the Index method when debugging and each property is assigned a value. I have also been able to new up a NewCreditCardApplicationDetails object in the controller and attempt to map that, but i get the same result. it's definitely a problem with my mapping somewhere because the object being passed in as source is definitely ok. thanks again.

Comment: That's very strange. Can you post the two class definitions involved?

Comment: i have added the class definitions to question. thanks again

Comment: The parameter object (applicationDetails) is not null and has some initialized values?

Comment: hi thanks for coming on board here too! yes - applicationDetails has values for it's properties

Comment: I double checked multiple examples and documentations how to use AutoMapper and everything was identical like yours.. So maybe you create a new empty project and try it with a "clean" again

Comment: yes, that might just be the way to go... see what happens at least. many thanks for your time