# Automapper create destination type object with no values inside

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

i have come across a similar problem as mentioned in this question [AutoMapper setting destination object to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302237/automapper-setting-destination-object-to-null/73811465?noredirect=1#comment130335838_73811465)

my mapper is creating an empty object of destination type although i can see values in my source object in debugger.

my source object is a grpc message of submitOrder type

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "SubmitOrderService";

package tracksubmitorder;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

service SubmitOrderService {

  rpc SubmitOrder(submitOrder) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message submitOrder {
  int64 orderID= 1;
  int32 beef =2;
  int32 chicken =3;
  int32 tofu =4;
  int32 shrimp =5;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp createdOn = 20;
  string comment=30;
}
```

my destination is a data model

```
namespace SubmitOrderService.Models
{
    public class Submit_Order
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public int CountBeef { get; set; }

        public int  CountChicken { get; set; }
        public int CountTofu { get; set; }
        public int CountShrimp { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

this is my profile file

```
using AutoMapper;
using SubmitOrderService.Models;

namespace SubmitOrderService
{
    public class SubmitOrderProfile: Profile
    {
        public SubmitOrderProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<submitOrder, Submit_Order>().ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Comments,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.Comment}")
                ).ForMember(
                    dest => dest.CreatedAt,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.CreatedOn }")
                )
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.CountChicken ,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.Chicken}")
                )
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.CountBeef ,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.Beef}")
                )
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.CountShrimp ,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.Shrimp}")
                )
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.CountTofu ,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.Tofu}")
                ).ReverseMap();

        }
    }
}
```

this is my  line for mapping where reqOrder is of type submitOrder

```
var order1 = _mapper.Map<Submit_Order>(reqOrder);
```

ps. This is my first time trying out Automapper, so any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: solved the problem.
I had to explicitly convert google.protobuf.Timestamp to DateTime for my CreatedAt member. like this,

ForMember(
                    dest => dest.CreatedAt,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CreatedOn.ToDateTime())
                )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem. I had to explicitly convert **google.protobuf.Timestamp** to **DateTime** for my **CreatedAt** member. like this,

```
ForMember( dest => dest.CreatedAt, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CreatedOn.ToDateTime()) )
```